# How can I add Edit (Crud) functionality with Java?

Tags: java, crud

I want to create add an edit  functionality (`public void EditPatientData()`) to edit the patients surname, firstname,
dateOfBirth, Length and weight. In other words I want to be able to edit the Patient's in the system Id, Surname, firtstname etc.

```
     import java.text.DecimalFormat;
     import java.time.LocalDate;
     import java.time.Period;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Collection;
     import java.util.Iterator;
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Patient {
        private static final int RETURN = 0;
        private static final int SURNAME = 1;
        private static final int FIRSTNAME = 2;
        private static final int DATEOFBIRTH = 3;
        private static final int LENGTH = 4;
        private static final int WEIGHT = 5;
        private static final int EDIT = 6;

        private int id;
        private String surname;
        private String firstName;
        private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
        private double length;
        private double weight;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public int getId() {
        return id;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
          return surname;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
          return dateOfBirth;
        }

        public double getLength() {
          return length;
        }

        public double getWeight() {
          return weight;
        }
// Method to calculate the age of a patient

           public int calcAge(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        //Code gets current date
           LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
        //If else statement that checks if both dates are not null/
        if ((dateOfBirth != null) && (curDate != null)) {
         /*if dates are both not null the code will take the birthdate and currentdate and
         calculate the difference the code will calculate the age in years */
         return Period.between(dateOfBirth, curDate).getYears();
      } else {
         //if one or both dates are null the code will return 0
         return 0;
      }
    }


//this code formats the double in 2 decimals so it looks cleaner

     private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

     //this code calculates the BMI of the patient
     public String calcBMI(double weight, double length) {
       return df.format(weight / (length * length));
     }

    


// Constructor
 
     Patient(int id, String surname, String firstName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, double weight, 
      double length) {
      this.id = id;
      this.surname = surname;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
      this.weight = weight;
      this.length = length;
      }

     
// Display patient data.
  
     public void viewData() {
      System.out.format("===== Patient id=%d ==============================\n", id);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "Surname:", surname);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "firstName:", firstName);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "Date of birth:", dateOfBirth);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "Age:", calcAge(dateOfBirth));
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "Weight in KG:", weight);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "Length in M:", length);
      System.out.format("%-17s %s\n", "The Patients BMI:", calcBMI(weight, length));
      }

      
// Shorthand for a Patient's full name1

     public String fullName() {
      return String.format("%s %s [%s]", firstName, surname, dateOfBirth.toString(), 
     calcAge(dateOfBirth), weight, length, calcBMI(weight, length));
     }

     
 //Edit patient data.
     public void EditPatientData() {

     }
    }
```

Comment: If you want objects of your class to be mutable, add [setter methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) in addition to the getter you already wrote. Other than that, I’ve no idea what you mean by “edit”. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am creating an application for doctors at the hospital. What I mean is that I want to be able to edit the Patient in the system Id, Surname, firtstname etc.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by add & edit?
If add mean you want to add a patient! Then you can use your Patient constructor to create(add) New Patient.
If you want to edit a Patient then you need to add a setters for your fields and use these setters to edit some values for your patient object.

Comment: To create setters                  
public void setId(int id) {this.id=id;}  public void setSurname(String name) {this.surname=name;} 
 public void setFristName(String name) {this.fristName=name;}
 public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate date) {this.dateOfBirth= date;} 
public void setLength(doule length) {this.length=length} 
  public void setWeight(doule weigth) {this.weigth=weigth;} 
  if you want to edit for example weigth by 76 use setWeigth(76);

Comment: Please add the code by editing the post. Do not add code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to add 2 patients you will need an array. It is best practice that keep all your logic work methods in different classes rather than Patient- data class.
In this case, you will basically not need any getter or setter method. The constructor will be more than enough here.

Check methods and try to understand the logic.

We have basic few line codes that we have used them 2 3 times but every time it helped us do different things. For example, fillMethod() helps us in registration,  also with updates. Always try to write code that you can use for many things.

I hope it will help

Step 1: Create one config and first add an array:
It will store patients' index. So when you want to update let's say, the 4th patient, you will call basically the 4th patient and you will update it.

```
public class Config {
    //Patient's data
    public static Patient[] patients= null;
}
```

Step 2: Create InputUtil class and add 3 main methods: registerPatients(), printRegisteredPatients() and updatePatients()

```
public class PatientUtil {

    //this method for register
    public static void registerPatients() {
        //to set Config Patients array size. How
        int numberOfPatients=  //many patients you will register, write num

        Config.patients= new Student[numberOfPatients];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ".Register");//1. Register
            //we put patient to the index
            Config.patients[i] = PatientUtil.fillPatient();
        }
        System.out.println("Registration completed successfully!");
        PatientUtil.printAllRegisteredPatirnts();
    }

//Step 3. Create fillPatient() method to fill the patient
// this method will help us register and uptade time

public static Patient fillPatient() {
   PAtient patient = new Patient(int id, String surname, String firstName, 
   LocalDate dateOfBirth, double weight, 
              double length);
     return patient;
        }


//Step4: Print all registered patients
public static void printAllRegisteredPatients() {
    if (Config.patients== null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Config.patients.length; i++) {
        Patient pt = Config.patients[i];
        System.out.println((i+1)+"."+pt.fullname());//this is your toString method
    }
}

//Step5 Update Patients
  public static Patient updatePatient(){
    int updatePatientAtThisIndex = //write number that you want to update exact patient
    System.out.println("Enter the details: ");
    Patient updatingPatient = PatientUtil.fillPatient();// asking new student details
    Config.patients[updatePatientAtThisIndex ]=updatingPatient ;//updating that index we asked before with new data
 }
}
```